# xcode - making strings localizable through script

Tags: ruby, xcode, scripting, localizable.strings

I've been using the xcodeproj gem to automate some of the work that I need to do. Part of it is adding files to xcode projects. I've gotten the references to add but I noticed that the string files I'm adding are not marked as localized but they are placed in an `en.lproj` folder.

Does xcode need to have them marked as localized if they're in this folder, or is that sufficient? And if it's required that they have the localized option checked, is there a way to do this through script?

I've done about as much googling as I can to figure this out and I'm coming up short. Everything I've tried has failed. I've gone so far as to compare the project.pbx files before and after the check is marked but the changes don't seem consistent or to follow a pattern I can duplicate.

Any advice?